# HTML5 storage for ul list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use session storage for list items. This doesn't seem to be working and because of the styling, I can't use the basic select/option:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span data-bind="label">Day</span><span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" name="country">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
var item = window.localStorage.getItem('country');
$('ul[name=country]').val(item);

$('ul[name=country]').change(function() {
   window.localStorage.setItem('country', $(this).val());
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12203/)

Comment: UL's don't have a value, and they never change(); what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `val` in a `ul` tag, and it does not have `value` property.

Also, you're trying to use a `change` event on it, and it does not have that event either.

First, you must understand what you're doing there. You've probably copied this *Dropdown Picker* from anywhere else, and you don't understand what it's doing.

It's simulating a `select` behavior by using a `label` inside a `button`, and anytime a `li` inside the `ul` tag is clicked, your code changes the `label` text to the `li`'s one.

So, firstly, when your page is loaded, you must see if anything is already in your localStorage, and if it is, you must change the label's text to the value saved in the localStorage.

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('country');
if (item) $('span[data-bind="label"]').text(item);
```

After that, inside your `li`'s click event, you must save the clicked `li`'s text into the localStorage for persisting purposes later.

```
// Dropdown picker
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
  /* the rest of your code */
  localStorage.setItem('country', $target.text());
});
```

I've updated [your fiddle with the code working](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12204/).

Comment: You're right, I did copy that and do not understand what it's doing. Thank you for the help and explanation!

Comment: @bunnycode Np, man! Feel free to upvote and accept my answer =)

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic `click()` event. You should not use `change()`:

```
$('ul[name=country] li').click(function() {
   window.localStorage.setItem('country', $(this).text());
});
```

Check in the console, using `localStorage.getItem("country")`.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5z0nkdjb/**